# Mockito how to pass type to generic supplyAsync method that returns a CompleteableFuture?

Tags: java, concurrency, mocking, mockito, powermock

Suppose I Have an Executor:

```
public class ExecutorUtil {
private ExecutorService executorService;

public <T> CompletableFuture<T> supplyAsync(Supplier<T> supplier) {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(supplier, executorService);
}
}
```

and calls to the generic supplyAsync methods like:

```
public CompletableFuture<List<String>> getBuryListFuture(){
    CompletableFuture<List<String>> buryFuture = executorUtil.supplyAsync( () -> {
        List<String> burySkus = null;
        try {
            System.out.println("Here bury:");
            burySkus = ruleEngine.getBuriedSkus();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.info("[ERROR]: There is some issue with RuleEngine");
        }
        return burySkus;
    });
    return buryFuture;
}
```

and:

```
public<Source> CompletableFuture<List<StrategyDTO>> getStrategyListFuture(Source source){

    CompletableFuture<List<StrategyDTO>> strategyFuture = executorUtil.supplyAsync( () -> {
        List<StrategyDTO> strategyList;
        try {
            strategyList = recommendationService.execute(source).getStrategies();
            strategyList = removeDuplicates(strategyList);
        } catch (OrchestrationException e) {
            throw new CompletionException(e);
        }
        return strategyList;
    });
    return strategyFuture;
}
```

How to get mockito to mock different responses from executor for each of these calls ? So far, i am only able to mock same response for both.

using:

```
CompletableFuture<Object> future3 = new CompletableFuture<>();
future3.complete(recResponse.getStrategies());
PowerMockito.when(executorUtil.supplyAsync(Matchers.any())).thenReturn(future3);
```

Tried differentiating with:

```
PowerMockito.when(executorUtil.supplyAsync(Matchers.<Supplier<List<String>>>any())).thenReturn(future4);
    PowerMockito.when(executorUtil.supplyAsync(Matchers.<Supplier<List<StrategyDTO>>>any())).thenReturn(future3);
```

But it makes no difference.